# I have fetched data row wise with duplicate ID(Showing in Question)but i Want it as per output show in (Output)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Data fetched from simple SQL Query(Question):

```
Id  comment
--------------------------------
1   approved
1   changed
1   hold
2   approved
3   changed
4   hold
```

I want the output like below:

```
Id  Comment  Comment Comment
---------------------------------------------
1   approved Changed Hold
2   approved Null    Null
3   Changed  Null    Null
4   hold     Null    Null
```

Means I want all comments of ID 1 in one row using sql query

```
select *
from status
```

An ID can have no more than three comments.

Comment: Yes. It always 3.   I am using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then comment end) as comment_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then comment end) as comment_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then comment end) as comment_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```